# GRUB keeps disappearing on dual Boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot

I have an HP ProDesk computer and need to keep it in Dual Boot, including Windows 10 and Xubuntu 18.04. I install Windows 10 and then Xubuntu. Everything works fine. But ocassionally, the grub menu simply stops coming up and when the machine is turned on, Windows comes up automatically. This is a computer for which I create an image and then it is installed in 20 machines in a lab. During a semester, this keeps happening with some of them, apparently randomly. I am using a machine whose grub menu has just disappeared. I booted it using Xubuntu in a pen drive and run boot repair to extract the following report

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gkqsVbtPS4/

Can someone help, please?

Comment: Everything looks fine. What might be happening is some Windows feature update changing ther boot order back to Windows. You should check that in UEFI settings before using boot-repair.

Answer (score 1):

You may [need to edit the items in `/EFI/Boot/`](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2392797), replacing the default Windows bootloader with a renamed copy of `shimx64.efi`. On one HP machine I've had, BIOS ignored any but the Windows bootloader.

If you plan to make this change, *make a disk image first*, and also rename the old Windows bootloader to save it, as any issue could make it difficult to get back to where you were.